# Implementation of an interface which contains a struct

Tags: go

I am bit confused about how the typesets in go work. Post Go 1.18, go supports embedding structs inside an interface. For instance, this is perfectly valid go code :

```
type ABCInterface interface {
    ABC
}
type ABC struct {
    A, B, C int
}
```

My question is how do I instantiate an object which satisfies the ABCInterface?

I tried creating instance of ABC but that is not of type ABCInterface.
I also defined a new struct

```
type ABCImpl struct {
  ABC
}
```

but this is not an implementation of ABCInterface as well.

Comment: `ABC` is in the type set of `ABCInterface`, it can therefore be used as the type argument when instantiating a generic function or struct that have `ABCInterface` as their type parameter, see: https://go.dev/play/p/rryTq45cBSi. `ABCImpl` on the other hand is neither `ABC` nor does it implement `ABCInterface`.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please show the code you expected to work but doesn't.

Comment: "My question is how do I instantiate an object which satisfies the ABCInterface?" You cannot. This type of interface is only useful as a constraint in generics.

Answer (score 2):

In Go, an interface is a set of method signatures that define the behavior that a struct (or type) must adhere to. When a struct implements all the methods specified by an interface, it is said to satisfy or implement that interface.

In your case, let's consider that you want an interface that implements a `Sum` method. To implement the interface, you'll add the listener as follows:

```
package main

import "log"

// ABCInterface provides a blueprint for types that include the Sum method.
type ABCInterface interface {
    Sum() int
}

// ABC is a type that represents values of A, B, and C.
type ABC struct {
    A, B, C int
}

// ABCImpl is a type that inherits fields from ABC and implements ABCInterface.

type ABCImpl struct {
    ABC
}
//You could eliminate the `ABC` struct and simply use
type ABCImpl struct {
   A,B,C int
}


// Sum calculates the sum of A, B, and C and returns the result.
func (a ABCImpl) Sum() int {
    return a.C + a.A + a.B
}

func main() {
    // Create an instance of ABCImpl.
    trialValue := ABCImpl{
        ABC: ABC{
            A: 1,
            B: 2,
            C: 3,
        },
    }
    
    // Call the Sum method on the trialValue instance and print the result.
    log.Println(trialValue.Sum())
}
```